# Select data from two tables and listing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, html-table

I have following structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :Hobbies, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hobbies, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Hobby < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :User
end
```

In my **Users_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @data = User.all(:joins => :hobbies)
  end
```

In **index.html.erb**

```
  <% for item in @data %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.id %></td> #from table Users
      <td><%= item.hobby_name %></td> #from table Hobbies
     </tr>
  <% end %>
```

And this gives me an error **undefined method `hobby_name' for # User:0x103cf7480>**

I thought that I have that associations right, but this error makes confused... Can you help me someone, please, where could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the relation, your object doesn't have an attribute called hobby_name, it has an association to multiple hobbies, and each hobby has an attribute called hobby_name

So:

```
<% item.hobbies.each do |h| %>
<%= h.hobby_name %>
<% end %>
```